# toggling class to retrigger animation

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I have a banner ad with multiple @keyframes css animations that I am trying to set to loop 3 times.

I am trying to adapt this code to suit my purposes:

http://jsfiddle.net/26GUe/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loops = 3 * 2;
    function removeAddClass() {
        $("#button").toggleClass("animate");
        if (--loops > 0)
             setTimeout(removeAddClass, 2000);
    }
    removeAddClass();
});
```

I want it to load with 'animate' on, play for 10 seconds, reset (remove class for <1 second), and then repeat 2x more.

Can you help?

Here is a fiddle roughly of what I have now:

https://jsfiddle.net/whatmyth2k/90azvfkj/14/

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP posted this question twice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018310/retriggering-css-animation-on-repeat-scroll

Comment: @disinfor when I went to edit my question, I accidentally opened a question i asked a year ago. Since deleted the duplicate, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

you're cancelling the animations by removing the `.animate` class before it can animate. You need to delay removing the class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var loops = 5; // 3 * 2 (6) ends on removeClass, so if you want it to remain on end state, set to odd number

  function removeAddClass() {
    var $el = $('#container')
    $("#container").toggleClass("animate");
    if (--loops > 1) {
      // WAIT 10s to remove class, so animation can finish
      var delay = $el.hasClass('animate') ? 10000 : 0
      setTimeout(removeAddClass, delay);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(removeAddClass, 10000);
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcwgzyx2/2/)